# why the for loop doesn't want to wait for the process to finish on a function at node js?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a script to download pages from multiple urls using node js but the loop didn't want to wait for the request to finish and continued printing, I also got a hint to use the async for loop, but still it didn't work.

here's my code

```
function GetPage(url){
    console.log(` Downloading page ${url}`);
    request({
        url: `${url}`
    },(err,res,body) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(` Writing html to file` );
        fs.writeFile(`${url.split('/').slice(-1)[0]}`,`${body}`,(err) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log('saved');
        });
    });
}
var list = [ 'https://www.someurl.com/page1.html', 'https://www.someurl.com/page2.html', 'https://www.someurl.com/page3.html' ]
const main = async () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        console.log(` processing ${list[i]}`);
        await GetPage(list[i]);
    }
};

main().catch(console.error);
```

Output :

```
 processing https://www.someurl.com/page1.html
 Downloading page https://www.someurl.com/page1.html
 processing https://www.someurl.com/page2.html
 Downloading page https://www.someurl.com/page2.html
 processing https://www.someurl.com/page3.html
 Downloading page https://www.someurl.com/page3.html
 Writing html to file
 Writing html to file
saved
saved
 Writing html to file
saved
```

Comment: I think GetPage returns immediately after being called. GetPage initiates request and returns without waiting.

Comment: you need to add `return` the result of the `request` call from GetPage, otherwise you're awaiting a null response (which resolves immediately)

Comment: `GetPage()` is not built around promises and doesn't even return a promise so `await` on its result does NOTHING.  `await` has no magic powers.  It awaits a promise.  If you don't give it a promise that properly resolves/rejects when your async operation is done, then the `await` does nothing.  Your `GetPage()` function returns nothing.

Comment: Also, the `request()` library is deprecated and not recommended for new projects.  You can look at a list of alternatives [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  I'd suggest [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) and then you can make it entirely promise-based by also use [`fs.promises.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_writefile_file_data_options).

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems with your code.
You are mixing code that uses the `callback` style programming and code that should be using promises. Also, your `getPage` function is not `async` (it doesn't return a promise) so you cannot `await` on it.

You just have to return a `promise` from your `getPage()` function, and correctly resolve it or reject it.

```js
function getPage(url) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(` Downloading page ${url}`);

    request({ url: `${url}` }, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) reject(err);

      console.log(` Writing html to file`);

      fs.writeFile(`${url.replace(/\//g,'-')}.html`, `${body}`, (writeErr) => {
        if (writeErr) reject(writeErr);

        console.log("saved");
        resolve();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

You don't have to change your `main()` function loop will `await` for the `getPage()` function.

Comment: I don't think you can do `fs.writeFile(\`${url}.html\`, ...)` because that won't be a legal filename if those are real URLs.

Comment: @jfriend00
I wasn't looking at that part of the code, but you are right about that. Fixed.

Comment: it's not real url and just for example only, but it's ok ... i edited it to avoid misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

For loop doesn't wait for callback to be finished, it will continue executing it. You need to turn either getPage function to promise or use Promise.all as shown below.

```
var list = [
  "https://www.someurl.com/page1.html",
  "https://www.someurl.com/page2.html",
  "https://www.someurl.com/page3.html",
];

function getPage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(` Downloading page ${url}`);
    request({ url: `${url}` }, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      console.log(` Writing html to file`);
      fs.writeFile(`${url}.html`, `${body}`, (writeErr) => {
        if (writeErr) reject(writeErr);
        console.log("saved");
        resolve();
      });
    });
  });
}

const main = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let promises = [];
    list.map((path) => promises.push(getPage(path)));
    Promise.all(promises).then(resolve).catch(reject);
  });
};

main().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: I don't think you can do `fs.writeFile(\`${url}.html\`, ...)` because that won't be a legal filename if those are real URLs.

Answer (score 0):

`GetPage()` is not built around promises and doesn't even return a promise so `await` on its result does NOTHING.  `await` has no magic powers.  It awaits a promise.  If you don't give it a promise that properly resolves/rejects when your async operation is done, then the `await` does nothing.  Your `GetPage()` function returns nothing so the await has nothing to do.

What you need is to fix `GetPage()` so it returns a promise that is properly tied to your asynchronous result.  Because the `request()` library has been deprecated and is no longer recommended for new projects and because you need a promise-based solution anyway so you can use `await` with it, I'd suggest you switch to one of the alternative promise-based libraries recommended [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  My favorite from that list is [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got), but you can choose whichever one you like best.  In addition, you can use [`fs.promises.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_writefile_file_data_options) for promise-based file writing.

Here's how that code would look like using `got()`:

```
const got = require('got');
const { URL } = require('url');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

function getPage(url) {
    console.log(` Downloading page ${url}`);
    return got(url).text().then(data => {
        // can't just use an URL for your filename as it contains potentially illegal
        // characters for the file system
        // so, add some code to create a sanitized filename here

        // find just the root filename in the URL
        let urlObj = new URL(url);
        let filename = path.basename(urlObj.pathname);
        if (!filename) {
            filename = "index.html";
        }
        let extension = path.extname(filename);
        if (!extension) {
            filename += ".html";
        } else if (extension === ".") {
            filename += "html";
        }
        console.log(`  Writing file ${filename}`)
        return fs.promises.writeFile(filename, data);
    });
}

const list = ['https://www.someurl.com/page1.html', 'https://www.someurl.com/page2.html', 'https://www.someurl.com/page3.html'];
async function main() {
    for (let url of list) {
        console.log(` processing ${url}`);
        await getPage(url);
    }
}

main().then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(console.error);
```

If you put real URLs in the array, this is directly runnable in nodejs.  I ran it myself with my own URLs.

**Summary of Changes and Improvements:**

1. Switched from `request()` to `got()` because it's promise-based and not deprecated.
2. Modified `getPage()` to return a promise that represents the asynchronous operations in the function.
3. Switched to `fs.promises.writeFile()` so we are using only promises for asynchronous control-flow.
4. Added legal filename generation from the base path of the URL since you can't just use a full URL as a filename (at least in some file systems).
5. Switched to simpler for/of loop

Comment: @dtzyoru - Did you ever figure out your question?  If any of these answers helped you figure it out, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.